# How to SET OUT parameter when my stored procedure gets error?

Tags: stored-procedures, mariadb

I'm writing stored procedure on `mariadb 5.5` and trying to return error code when `SQL EXCEPTION` occurs in it.

My code is like below...

```
delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_test(
                             IN fooin  varchar(50),
                            INOUT fooout varchar(50)
                              )
BEGIN

   DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
   BEGIN
      SET fooout = '9999'; #which means error
      RESIGNAL;
   END;

   SET fooout = '0000';
   select now_(); # Error happens here on my purpose
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

The result is like below...

```
MariaDB [emsdevdb]> call sp_test('foo',@result);
ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION emsdevdb.now_ does not exist
MariaDB [emsdevdb]> select @result;             
+---------+
| @result |
+---------+
| NULL    |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Why `@result` prints NULL instead of '9999'?

How to return my own error-code for the case of `SQL EXCEPTION`?

`NULL` value of `out` parameter means that stored procedure encount an error?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_test$$

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_test(
  IN fooin varchar(50),
  INOUT fooout varchar(50)
)
BEGIN
  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
  BEGIN
    SET fooout = '9999'; #which means error
    -- RESIGNAL;
  END;

  SET fooout = '0000';
  SELECT now_(); # Error happens here on my purpose
END$$

DELIMITER ;

SET @result := NULL;

CALL sp_test('foo', @result);

SELECT @result;
```